# Plane quartics and morphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Suppose that $C$ is a non-hyperelliptic genus 3 curve defined over $\mathbb{Q}$.
It is well known that non-hyperelliptic genus 3 curves are plane quartics, and these are also trigonal. So we have a morphism $C \mapsto \mathbb{P}^{1}$ of degree $3$, and the way in which one usually constructs this map is choosing a point $P$ in $C$ and projecting from $P$ to $\mathbb{P}^{1} \subseteq \mathbb{P}^{2}.$

I am now wondering whether one can deduce that the degree 3 map $C \mapsto \mathbb{P}^{1}$ can always be defined over $\mathbb{Q}$. If we have a rational point $P$ on $C$, then I guess you can always find a rational map $C \mapsto \mathbb{P}^{1}$ defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ by the above construction. Moreover, if $C$ admits a model of the form $ax^4+ay^4+ \text{lower order terms} =0$ for $a$ some fourth power, then I guess this is doable too.

I am now wondering whether one can always ensure that there's a degree $3$ map which is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ if $C$ is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1):

If $D$ is a degree 3 divisor class on $C$ with $h^0(D) = 2$ then by Riemann-Roch $h^1(D) = 1$ and by Serre duality $h^0(K_C - D) = 1$. Therefore, $K_C - D$ is an effective divisor of degree $1$, hence it is linearly equivalent to a point $P$, hence $D$ is linearly equivalent to $K_C - P$.

Comment: I see - thank you. I take it that this implies that the answer to my question is no then? - i.e. the degree 3 map is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ iff $K_{C} - P$ is a rational divisor iff $P$ is rational point on $C$ (Since $K_{C}$ is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$). So we can get a degree $3$ map to $\mathbb{P}^{1}$ iff $C$ has a rational point.